# Best Practice re SDF file location?

Tags: sql-server-ce

I am writing a SQL Compact database app with an SDF database that I need to install on the user's machine. The user needs to be able to read and write to the database, and the database needs to be available to all users. The app has to run with normal user rights, and UAC can't be disabled.

Where is the best place to place the database on the user's machine? I had thought `c:\ProgramData` was the preferred location, but checking its user permissions, I see that normal users only have read permission. So, I am looking for an alternative. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of any clear guidance on this issue, I have settled on `c:\Users\Public\Documents` as the location for the data file. If there is a better location for this file, I'd sure like to hear about it. I'll leave this question open for a couple more days before accepting my own answer.

Comment: On Windows XP there is no C:\Users? So perhaps that would be equivalent to C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data

Answer (score 2):

I only stick files in (Username)\Documents" if they would be opened or saved directly by a user, say if they double clicked and opened via Explorer. Given its an SDF I'd probably place it in %APPDATA%\(Company Name)\(Product Name)

Answer (score 2):

You should always place any files needed to be freely modified by the user in the Application Data folder. In this case the Common Application data folder which is available to all users.  this allows the app to be able to modify this file without requiring elevated permissions.

This is how you get the path to Common Application Data folder.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
```

Comment: The database file needs to be available to All Users